# How to control auto opened Datepicker in materilize CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/78125vs0/126/)

```
   <input type="date" class="datepicker">

    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
   });
```

> After select the date from the date-picker, when we moved to next tab on window and again you came back current window the date-picker has opened automatically.

Comment: in materialize css datepicker automatically open when focus is go that control if you dont need to open datepicker focus is set to another control.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    onClose: function(){
        $('.datepicker').blur();
        $('.picker').blur();
       }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ujbv2yz/

Comment: this is the best solution that I looking for